# Kafka streams, branched output to multiple topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In my DSL based transformation, I have a stream-->branch, where in I want branched output redirected to multiple topics.
Current `branch.to()` method accepts only a `String`.
Is there any simple option with `stream.branch` where I can route the result to multiple topics. With a consumer, I can subscribe to multiple topics by providing an array of string as topics.

My problem requires me to take multiple actions if particular predicate satisfies a query.

I tried with `stream.branch[index].to(string)`, but this is not sufficient for my requirement. I am looking for something like `stream.branch[index].to(string array of topics)` or `stream.branch[index].to(string)`.

I expect the `branch.to` method with multiple topics or is there any alternate way to achieve the same with streams?

adding sample code.Removed actual variable names.

My Predicates

```
    Predicate <String, MyDomainObject> Predicate1 = new Predicate<String, MyDomainObject>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String key, MyDomainObject domObj) {
            boolean result = false;
    if condition on domObj
            return result;
        }
    };
    Predicate <String, MyDomainObject> Predicate2 = new Predicate<String, MyDomainObject>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String key, MyDomainObject domObj) {
            boolean result = false;
    if condition on domObj
            return result;
        }
    };

    KStream <String, MyDomainObject>[] branches= myStream.branch(
            Predicate1, Predicate2
    );


// here I need your suggestions.

// this is my current implementation
branches[0].to(singleTopic),
            Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(inSer, deSer)));

// I want to send notification to multiple topics. something like below

branches[0].to(topicList),
            Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.serdeFrom(inSer, deSer)));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you include some of the code that you tried in it's context. I know you included some in the paragraph, but it'd be great to see your entire function in a code block.

Comment: Like this? https://gist.github.com/nfo/c4936a24601352db23b18653a8ccc352

Comment: I have updated my original post with the code I am using.

Answer (score 1):

If you know to which topics you want to send the data, you can do the following:

```java
branches[0].to("first-topic");
branches[0].to("second-topic");
// etc.
```

Comment: Thank you @Matthias, I tried that, but then it was sending messages two times on the topic , probably because predicate was satisfying the same condition for both cases.

Comment: `branch()` sends each record into exactly one branch. Thus, it's unclear to me how a single record could be written into the same topic twice (of course, if case if failure, Kafka give at-least-once guarantees by default what might introduce duplicate -- but I assume that is not the problem?). Maybe you can update you question, share you code and explain what message is written into the same topic multiple times?